# Keep a WebClient() loaded?

Tags: c#

I am wondering how I would keep a `WebClient().DownloadString` loaded?
I am trying to load in a webpage but it has a Loading... section before it so when I am doing:

```
public static string wtfSkins = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://www.wtfskins.com/roulette");
```

It is always bringing up the Loading page.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what the question is.  Please elaborate.

Comment: It says loading because it is supposed to load when you first get the page in your browser. Page gets json via Ajax calls and render content dynamically using Javascript. Method `DownloadString()` only shows you the initial Html page but it's not going to run the scripts embedded in the code. These scripts are who actually do the job. Need a browser to run them or an automated tool or library running browser in background like Selenium, iMacros, etc. Good luck.